# Statistics by days, Select from database php and MySQLi

Tags: javascript, php, sql, mysqli

I make a php code that insert to my database today days with the count
but I want to show it in my diagram (Javascript) 
The code of diagram is

```js
  var lineChartData = {
 labels : ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30"],
 datasets : [
 {
  fillColor : "rgba(252, 130, 19, 0.74)",
  strokeColor : "#FC8213",
  pointColor : "#FC8213",
  pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
  data : [0,0,4,159,50,0,30,15,0,159,4,159,50,0,30,15,0,0,4,159,50,0,30,15,9,5,1,5,3,7]
   },
        ]

 };
new Chart(document.getElementById("line").getContext("2d")).Line(lineChartData);
```

So, I want to make days in Labels, but for example I have I my database like this :

```
2016-06-01 | 0 , 2016-06-02 | 10 , ... , 2016-06-07 | 59 , 2016-06-08 | 10
```

I want to:

`select data where month = this month (date(m))`

But I don't know how I can make it? And, I want to count(`*`) for per month like:

```
Month 1 = 1590 visits 
Month 2 = 1589 visits | Month 3 = 200 visits | Month 6 = 1590 visits.
```

And I want to count result for the last 3 years like

```
2014 = 159200 visits | 2015 = 187951 visits | 2016 = 2000 visits
```

How can I make all this ? I try a lot but any result :'(

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT sum(likes_field) from your_table group by MONTH(date_field)
```

For yearly count, you can use MySQL's YEAR(date_field) function.

you can add more constrains like limit or order by as you require.

Comment: And about count the last 3 years ?